# How to build this regular expression?

Tags: regex

Sample: `AAAATGCCCTAAGGGATGTTTTAGAAA`

I want to capture all string with these criteria:

Start: `ATG`
Follow by 3x characters of sets: A or C or G or T
End: `TAA` or `TAG` or `TGA`

Such as: `ATGCCCTAA`, `ATGTTTTAG`

I had a regular expression here: `/[ACGT]*((ATG)(([ACGT]){3})+(TAA|TAG|TGA))[ACGT]*/g`, but it only match the last `ATGTTTTAG` not `ATGCCCTAA`. I don't know why ?

Please help me write pattern that match both `ATGCCCTAA` and `ATGTTTTAG`.

Here is online example:
https://regex101.com/r/iO8lF9/1

Comment: We ask here that questions are not marked as "urgent" or other forms of help begging. All questions here are of equal importance. If you genuinely need urgent assistance, it is possible you need to hire a freelancer.

Comment: I don't get why the downvotes here! Problem described, effort in solving it, examples, even a fiddle !! What is people want more than that???

Answer (score 5):

This regex works well `/(ATG(?:A{3}|C{3}|G{3}|T{3})(?:TAA|TAG|TGA))/g`

as you can see here: https://www.regex101.com/r/gZ0zA9/2

I hope it helps

Comment: You seem to have `:?` the wrong way round, should be `?:`

Comment: @AeroX you're absolutely right! Thank you. I'm going to edit this right now.

Comment: You could also move the T in the last group out of the disjunction: `(ATG(?:AAA|CCC|GGG|TTT)T(?:AA|AG|GA))` that should be a little faster ...

Comment: @Markus at first sight I tought your regex was faster, but when i tried it on regex101, the analyzer shows me a number of step (91) greater than the number of steps of mine (79). Thus at the moment my regexp is the fastest (at least for the regex implementation used by regex101)

Comment: I've compared it using regexhero.net (there is a benchmark tool in the top ribbon) - but you are absolutely right, it depends on the implementation anyway ... (the fastest one for me was this so far: `ATG(?:A{3}|C{3}|G{3}|T{3})T(?:AA|AG|GA)`)

Answer (score 0):

Using back-reference you can shorten your regex as this:

```
ATG([AGCT])\1{2}(?:TGA|TA[AG])
```

[RegEx Demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/qX3iG0/2)

It matches `[AGCT]` after `ATG` and groups it as captured group #1. Next we match `\1{2}` to make sure same letter is repeated 3 times.

Answer (score -1):

try...

```
^ATG[AGCT]{3}(TAA|TAG|TGA)$
```

Comment: If I understand it right this part `[AGCT]{3}` should be `(A{3}|G{3}|C{3}|T{3})+` because `[AGCT]` would allow any combination

Comment: Thank you, i use this pattern

Comment: @JorgeCampos perhaps you are right - it is not clear if the set must be repeating characters or not. I think you should not have the `+` as I understood it to be exactly 3 characters between the start and end tokens.

Comment: @BillyMoon Oh yeah, no need for the `+` sign!

Answer (score -1):

I use this pattern and it works, thank all you for helping me.
/(ATG(:?A{3}|C{3}|G{3}|T{3})(:?TAA|TAG|TGA))/g

Comment: It's my pattern, I'm glad it helped. Please mark my answer as the accepted one since it worked.Thank you!